# Overlapping audio in IE when I show/hide videos

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, flv

I have a thumbnail list with links to individual videos. Everything works fine in all browsers but IE. In IE, if I start a video and (without clicking pause or stop) click on the thumbnail for the next video, the audio continues playing. In other words, the audio for both videos plays at once. Any suggestions?

HTML:

```
    <ul class="videoButtons">
    <li><a class="vidButton" href="javascript:void(0)" id="1" ><img src="images/videoPics/vid1Thumb.jpg" /><br />video title</a></li>
    <li><a class="vidButton" href="javascript:void(0)" id="2" ><img src="images/videoPics/vid2Thumb.jpg" /><br />video title</a></li>
    <li><a class="vidButton" href="javascript:void(0)" id="3" ><img src="images/videoPics/vid3Thumb.jpg" /><br />video title</a></li>
    </ul>

<div class="box" id="video1">
     <!--flv embedded object - FLVPlayer-->
</div>
<div class="box" id="video2">
    <!--flv embedded object - FLVPlayer1-->
</div>
<div class="box" id="video3">
     <!--flv embedded object - FLVPlayer2-->
</div>
```

Show/Hide code:

```
$(".vidButton").click(function()
{
var buttonID = $(this).attr('id'); // get ID of the button clicked
var video = $('#'+'video'+buttonID); // add ID number to video
$('.box').hide(); // hide all other divs
video.fadeTo("slow", 1); // show video
});
});
// video objects
swfobject.registerObject("FLVPlayer");
swfobject.registerObject("FLVPlayer1");
swfobject.registerObject("FLVPlayer2");
```

Comment: What flash player are you using? You're probably going to have to stop the video when you click on another thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading all the different players in the background, consider loading a single player and if available use the API's commands to load a video from a different URL in that instance. When not using an API, you'd probably want to dynamically add / remove the appropriate object to the browser's DOM.

**Code example** (*for the latter option*)**:**

```
$(".vidButton").click(function()
{
    if ($('#video_container embed').length() > 0) $('#video_container embed').remove(); // remove an existing player from the DOM if it exists

    var buttonID = $(this).attr('id'); // get ID of the button clicked
    var dyn_object = document.createElement("embed"); // create a dynamic HTML embed object
    $(dyn_object).appendTo($('#video_container')); // append the object to the DOM before doing anything to avoid potential memory leaks
    $(dyn_object).attr("type", "application/x-shockwave-flash");
    $(dyn_object).attr("src", "http://www.website.com/player.swf");
    $(dyn_object).attr("flashvars", "file=http://www.website.com/movies/movie_" + buttonID + ".flv");
    // ... optionally add more attributes here
});
```